# Making API calls with a master token - Do I always need an intermediary

Tags: rest, authentication, restful-authentication

A general web question, say I want to make an API call to do something like update a users address.

The API requires a secret token in its request (a master token). So naturally I cannot send keep this in my JS code as anyone could easily take a look at the code or just look at the request headers.

So in general, are situations like this handled in the following steps (taking a case of wanting to update a user's email):

- On the client (requesting side) - generate some sort of unique signature
- The client then sends the request to update their email along with that signature to an intermediary (server side)
- That intermediary validates the signature then makes the actual API call with the master token

I can't think of any other way - or is there some way I can avoid having the intermediary of validating the client? But even then the master token would somehow reside on the client side?

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The master token is same for all clients? Is it not generated dynamically for each client?

Comment: Yep - in this specific case I have its the same for all.